# Automatically adjusting the bucket size to get 10 buckets spanning the whole range

Tags: sql, presto

The following query works perfectly:

```sql
select
  floor(duration / 100) * 100 as bucket,
  count(*) as count
from flights
group by floor(duration / 100) * 100
order by bucket asc
```

However, I tried to make the bucket size automatically adjust to the range of values, so that there are 10 buckets in total spanning the whole range:

```sql
select
  floor(duration / (max(duration)/10)) * (max(duration)/10) as bucket,
  count(*) as count
from flights
group by floor(duration / (max(duration)/10)) * (max(duration)/10)
order by bucket asc

-- SYNTAX_ERROR: GROUP BY clause cannot contain aggregations or window functions: ["max"("duration"), "max"("duration")]
```

The idea in this failing query was to use the max value (assuming the min is 0) in order to derive the bucket size. Is there a way to make it work, or to use a better approach altogether?

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly calculate `max(duration)` using separate subquery.
Replace `max(duration)` with `(SELECT max(duration) FROM flights)`.

As a side effect, `flights` table will be read twice.
It should be read exactly twice, not more. You can verify that by running `EXPLAIN <your query>` and searching for `Scan` in the output.
If `flights` gets scanner more than twice, this can be further improved.
In fact, the improved version might be easier to read (I also used shorthand `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` clauses by referring to first select item):

```
SELECT
  floor(duration / (max_duration/10)) * (max_duration/10) as bucket,
  count(*) as count
FROM flights, (SELECT max(duration) max_duration FROM flights)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```